# Liferay upgrade from 3.2.3 to 6.0

Tags: liferay-6

I tried to upgrade from 5.2.3 to 6.0.6 Liferay bundle (mysql, tomcat).
unfortunately in some database tables such as user_ are overwritten and  the original data were lost.
Someone could help me,
 thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed the standard [Liferay upgrade procedure](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Upgrade+Instructions+%28disambiguation%29) then your data should still be there, albeit in a 'upgraded' form. If you didn't follow the correct procedures and didn't take a database and filesystem backup before the upgrade (always a good thing to do) than your data is unfortunately not recoverable anymore I fear.

Comment: thank's fimez,I've followed the step in http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Upgrade+Instructions+from+5.2+to+6.0 : i've substitute the portal.ext.properties of bundle 6.0 whit 5.2.3 ones and startup tomcat but some tables like user_ have been overwritten. what is wrong?

Comment: If the upgrade went correctly it shouldn't have overwritten the whole table(s), just upgraded/transformed them. I've tried out multiple upgrades and haven't seen Liferay effectively overwriting the user_ table. I guess it could happen if Liferay didn't detect the existing DB correctly in which case it will continue as if working on a fresh/new one and totally re-initialize the DB. Are there rows missing in your user_ table?

Comment: In practice, point to the database 5.2.3 correctly since some tables remain intact but for example the table user_ maintains only one row of the old table and the structure changes with the addition of new fields.You've never done the procedure completes successfully? Could you explain it to me step by step? Thank's

Comment: I've done a complete upgrade procedure a couple of times and successfully. The strange thing is that it doesn't really require a lot of work. The steps I use are: backup the current Liferay install (files + DB), download the new version and unpack that, configure the new Liferay to use the old data files and directory and start it. During starting it will automatically detect that it is working on data from an older version and upgrade it to the new version. In my cases this has always happened without any lost data.

Comment: Hello Fimez,
I managed to do the upgrade properly by removing the applications sevencogs and everything is working properly. Only upgrade thema custom does not work.I must just put the issue in Root? Thank's

Comment: Good to hear you having some success. We remove the sevencogs stuff by default as it doesn't serve any purpose other than being example/demo material.

Comment: Usually themes should continue to work reasonably after an upgrade, but as Liferay tends to change internally a bit it could be that certain tags/id/attributes have changed causing your custom theme to break. You should re-generate your custom theme based on the new plugins environment for your upgraded Liferay version. This will make sure the base Liferay theme you extend from is the correct one. Undeploy the old theme, clean your temp/work directories in Tomcat and redeploy the new theme.